# Getting possible point list inside of a path in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently trying something like below. But this works really slow than I expected. I guess  our responsible guy is the "FillContains" method. Any thoughts?

```
private void setCurrentPointList(Path path)
    {
        currentPointList = new List<Point>();
        for (int x = (int)path.Data.Bounds.X; x < ((int)path.Data.Bounds.X + (int)path.Data.Bounds.Width); x++)
        {
            for (int y = (int)path.Data.Bounds.Y; y < ((int)path.Data.Bounds.Y + (int)path.Data.Bounds.Height); y++)
            {
                if (path.Data.FillContains(new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(x, y, 1, 1))))
                {
                    currentPointList.Add(new Point(x, y));
                }
            }
        }

        Trace.WriteLine("Current Path's Point List Generated.");
    }
```

Edit: Sorry, I didn't wrote my goal. I'm trying to fill the path with another objects. Like a word cloud.